# AJAX Request on Mobile Devices NOT Working

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous, web

i have a problem making AJAX work on mobile devices, i have a simple site for Support Tickets... i CANT get the Async response from the server...

The Request is made but i dont get the response

Im testing in a table with Android 4.0.3 and in my Sony Xperi with 4.1.2

The page loads but it doesnt process the Javascript Async Requests

this is my code:

```
function ajaxAsyncRequest(htmlEntityTarget, progressTarget, requestKey, queryId) {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        document.getElementById(progressTarget).innerHTML = "Processing Request...";
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {            

            switch(requestKey) {
                case "loadTickets":
                    document.getElementById(htmlEntityTarget).innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;                                        
                    document.getElementById(progressTarget).innerHTML = "Done Processing! Tickets Loaded!";
                    break;
                case "loadTicketConversation":
                    document.getElementById(htmlEntityTarget).innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;                                        
                    document.getElementById(progressTarget).innerHTML = "Done Processing! Conversations Loaded!";
                    break;
                default:
                    document.getElementById(htmlEntityTarget).innerHTML = "failed response";
                    break;
            }

        }

    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://localhost/helpdesk/main/serverRouting/serverRoutingEntryPoint.php?key=" + requestKey + "&&queryId=" + queryId, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: On page load, the async request must load the users's tickets, but it doesnt...

Comment: The script runs fine on Desktop

Comment: If you're actually using this URL `"http://localhost/...` then your mobile device is talking to itself - no wonder it doesn't load the tickets.

Comment: Is the Android device actually running its own web server?

Comment: o.o No .. im running a local web server using Xampp

Comment: ooh.. mmm... i how do i fix that???

Comment: In The Future, the server will be on a PC. so i need to fix it anyway

Comment: You need to use a URL of the server that provides the service. If you're using a hosted service it will be your domain name. If you're using a local server it will be whatever name you have assigned it in your local DNS, assuming your mobile devices have Wifi connection. If they're using 3G or GPRS then things become more complicated.

Comment: That did it.. would u like to post your comment as the Answer?? so we can upvoted :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a URL of the server that provides the service. If you're using a hosted service it will be your domain name. If you're using a local server it will be whatever name you have assigned it in your local DNS, assuming your mobile devices have Wifi connection. If they're using 3G or GPRS then things become more complicated.